# Legendary Mirage Spot Requirements

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Can somebody help? I have been soaring every day trying to find Uxie, along with the Pathless Plain, Trackless Forest, Fabled Cave, and I also might want to know the chances of finding Crescent Island.